# How to submit a form from inside an iframe and have result be outside

Tags: javascript, forms, post, iframe

I have been trying to have a small login widget that I embed within a static page inside an iframe allow someone to log into my site.  The problem I get is that when the form posts it ends up appearing inside the iframe instead of as a full browser page.

I know it is possible to do this because https://www.salliemae.com/ employs the same strategy on their home page.  They embed an iframe inside their static page that does all their logic for them.  I have very similar javascript in that I call form.submit() when someone clicks.  The only difference is that I use jQuery to catch the click event vs putting the onclick directly on the form element.

I have looked at their code in their calm.js and it seems to be doing a simple form.submit() as I do, but their page loads fully in the browser vs only in the iframe.  I have looked around SO and not seen a similar post, so if I just missed it, please let me know.

Comment: If the request crosses domains, ports or protocols, browsers shoot it down. Google [**XSS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) for more information.

Comment: in my case (and the salliemae example above) they are both on the same domain.  So for the question, how do I do it assuming both are on the same domain?  Salliemae only has the lower level domain in common, they are on different subdomains (www. vs. login.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See `target="_top"` in the iframe's `<form>` tag. That tells the browser to load the response in the parent frame.

Comment: ahh, been banging my head on this trying to figure out what was the delta.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not ajax the content, you just add `target="_top"` to the form, otherwise you will have to use `window.open(*serialisedurl*,"_top")`